# Mostrar valor do objeto em vez do nome da classe

Tags: c#, .net, string, classes

Estou fazendo uma simples aplicação cadastro em *array*, mas quando executo aparece o seguinte resultado no console invés das informações que passei no parâmetro.

[image: aparece o nome da classe]

Segue o código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Veiculo[] veiculosArray = new Veiculo[10];

        veiculosArray[0] = new Veiculo("BMW", "DSR6646");

        Console.WriteLine(veiculosArray[0]);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Classe Veiculo:

```
class Veiculo
{
    public string Modelo { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Placa { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Veiculo(string modelo, string placa)
    {
        Modelo = modelo;
        Placa = placa;
    }

}
```

Comment: Agora você pode votar em tudo no site, dê uma olhada no [tour] como funciona. Pode votar também aqui, o voto é diferente da aceitação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O motivo específico deste erro é que você não criou um método [`ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) para sua classe, então o compilador usa um padrão que retorna o nome da classe. Sobrescrevendo esse método resolve esse problema, ainda tem vários outros conceituais na classe e todo o uso, ainda que seja um exercício.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var veiculosArray = new Veiculo[10] ;
        veiculosArray[0] = new Veiculo("BMW", "DSR6646");
        WriteLine(veiculosArray[0]);
    }
}
class Veiculo {
    public string Modelo { get; set; } = "";
    public string Placa { get; set; } = "";
    public Veiculo(string modelo, string placa) {
        Modelo = modelo;
        Placa = placa;
    }
    public override string ToString() => Placa;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8sT6Uv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r35Aot). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ToString.cs).